# Passive vs active voice in present simple

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

Does the sentence below refer to visitors of a barber shop or to barbers themselves?

```
Bad guys shave here.
```

Could you explain the rule that governs such expressions ?

Comment: Please wait a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you receive a good one right away. For why this is usually wise, read [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unambiguously active, but it is nonetheless ambiguous, because *shave* may be transitive, designating the act of shaving another, or intransitive, designating the act of shaving oneself. Consequently the sentence may mean that this is a place where barbers who are bad guys shave their clients (the Patient/Direct Object of the verb being inferred) or a place where men who are bad guys shave themselves.

The passive would entail the transitive sense, but it would require the verb to be expressed as *BE shaved*, with the Patient cast as Subject:

> Bad guys are shaved here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So, it is basically the transitivity of the verb `to shave` that makes it ambiguous. Is there any way to remove the ambiguity in such sentences (besides using passive voice) or they are intrinsically ambiguous?

Comment: @Konstantin There's rarely any ambiguity in context. If you see this on a sign, the place where it hangs is probably going to tell you which meaning is intended.

Comment: @Konstantin ...and the transitive _shave_ is not likely to be intended on such a sign, since few customers actively seek a barber who is a bad guy. Context is your friend. (Consider also, though, that _bad_ could here be an example of _inverted meaning._)

Comment: Wouldn't you expect the passive in such a context to be formed with _get?_ "Bad guys get shaved here." Also, _guys_ in such a context should be spelled with a _z._ ;)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Consider also that there is surely a market for people who want to get shaved by a bad guy. There is a tattoo parlor in my town named "[Evil by the Needle](https://twitter.com/EvilbytheNeedle/status/865675933230931968)". They might serve the same clientele as Konstantin's Barber Shop.

Comment: @BenKovitz In _Evil by the Needle_ we have entered _inverted meaning_ territory, don't you think? cf. _Bad to the Bone._ Me, I'm not letting any bad guys near my carotid with a straight razor.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I don't think it's inverted meaning. All societies have ways of showing respect and awe for the dark side, and a few people make a profession of it. Ghost stories, Halloween, [skull tattoos](https://www.google.com/search?q=skull+tattoos&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch), the Raiders logo, and the like aren't inverted ways of saying that murder, death, etc. are peaches and ice cream ; they're genuine, unironic ways of embracing and respecting the darkness.

Comment: @BenKovitz Having been to Sturgis and having witnessed the prevalence there of skull-themed tattoos, and having engaged in conversation (to use the term loosely) with some of the bearers, I can tell you that the dark side of which you speak is largely populated by overweight clerks who spend beyond their means on motorcycles adorned with lots of shiny things. If that ain't inverted (and perhaps not only in the linguistic sense), what is?

Comment: @BenKovitz My digression aside, I do think that _Bad Guys Shave Here_ is intended as an examplar of _inverted meaning._